# Exporting my app's database file from my development iPhone to my computer

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I've got an iPhone app under development that I plan on using for research purposes. As testers use the app on my development phone, it stores analytics data in a local database (right now SQLite, but I'm not opposed to migrating to CoreData).

After testing is done, I need to be able to copy this analytics database off of the phone onto my computer so I can run queries on the data. What is the easiest way to accomplish this? If necessary I'll iterate through the data, print it to the device log, and then import it back into a database on the desktop, but I'd like to find a way to just grab the .sqlite file without running it through an intermediary format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Xcode Organizer to download a zipped snapshot of your app's Documents and Library directories from your device.

Comment: Awesome! This made me realize that I can also upload data to the app so that I can seed it with database populated with specific information.

Answer (score 1):

You can always try to print it to a PDF, using the UIKit is a simple way to export information and formating in a easy way, unless you think this method can't apply to your database ;)

Do you know if we can email the SQLite database directly from the iOS device?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to add the `UIFileSharingEnabled` key (as a boolean, set to `YES`) to your Info.plist, then use something like this:

```
NSString *docsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:whereverTheDatabaseIs toPath:[docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"exported.sqlite"] error:NULL];
```

Then, you or your users will be able to grab the database off the device using iTunes's file-handling malarkey.

edited - actually, see Ole's answer: I didn't know about that trick, and it'll probably be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Thanx ole begemann.

In organizer open your app and then Download that particular send Box. So It will create a  .xcappdata  extension file.
You can rename the extension to .zip then you will find the same folder as in InApp directory folder in your finder. and you can work with your data.